# React Native upload image to server failed in android

Tags: react-native, upload, multipartform-data

i am using the following code to but i keep getting in android, which  was showing "Network request failed", but it was no problem if i not append photo file data in the FormData. Why I am getting this problem?

```js
    const data = new FormData();

    data.append("name", "testName"); // you can append anyone.
    data.append("photo", {
      uri: 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADMAAAAzCAYAAAA6oTAqAAAAEXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBwbmdjcnVzaEB1SfMAAABQSURBVGje7dSxCQBACARB+2/ab8BEeQNhFi6WSYzYLYudDQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgZmcvDqYGBgmhivGQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgbmQw+P/eMrC5UTVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==',
      type: 'image/png', // or photo.type
      name: 'testPhotoName.png'
    });
    fetch('https://ptsv2.com/t/1gfl7-1544694996/post', {
      method: "post",
      body: data
    }).then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
```

Comment: Do you have the app connected to the Debugger?

Comment: no, i just get started on react native and run it on android emulator in ubuntu.

Comment: I just tried your code (copy and pasted it into my `componentDidMount()` and I get  a 200 response with the message `Thank you for this dump. I hope you have a lovely day!`

Comment: can you share your configure, code and how you run the app? i keep geting same error and no matter i run it on avd or genymotion,thanks, following is my source
https://github.com/kuthreecar/react-native-android-upload-test